# How to get rid of the unwanted first output?

Tags: output-formatting, output

I have the following code:

```
$Pre = # /. ({i -> {1, E^(2 I \[Pi]/3)}, 
         j -> {1, E^(-2 I \[Pi]/3)}}) /. {x_, y_} -> 
       FullSimplify[(x/3 + Im[y]/Sqrt[3] - Re[y]/
            3) \[DoubleStruckI] + (x/3 - Im[y]/Sqrt[3] - Re[y]/
            3) \[DoubleStruckJ] + 1/3 (x + y + Conjugate[y])] & // 
    FullSimplify // Expand;

i^j
% // FullSimplify  // Expand
```

It prints two outputs, but I need only the second one (after `//FullSimplify //Expand`).
But if I remove the first output, and do `i^j// FullSimplify  // Expand`, the output is still unsimplified, and `Evaluate` does not help either.

What can be done here?

Comment: Do you know what $Pre is? It is: "a global variable whose value, if set, is applied to every input expression". I am finding it hard to understand what you could possibly be trying to accomplish...

Comment: Put a semicolon after the `i^j` ?

Comment: @LouisB Then the second line does not work.

Comment: Does this do it `$Pre = (# /. ({i -> {1, E^(2 I \[Pi]/3)}, j -> {1, E^(-2 I \[Pi]/3)}}) /. {x_, y_} -> FullSimplify[(x/3 + Im[y]/Sqrt[3] - Re[y]/3) \[DoubleStruckI] + (x/3 - Im[y]/Sqrt[3] -  Re[y]/3) \[DoubleStruckJ] + 1/3 (x + y + Conjugate[y])] // FullSimplify // Expand) &;` ?

Comment: @LouisB Yes! What did you change?

Comment: I moved the ampersand to the end and added parentheses around everything else.

Comment: @LouisB thanks!

Comment: note: `# + 1 & // g` yields `g[# + 1 &]`, so that `g` (here e.g. `FullSimplify`) gets given the actual function *itself* as the argument. (And then `$Pre[x]` ⇒ `g[# + 1 &][x]` is in all likelihood meaningless.) You can solve this by doing `# + 1 // g &` instead as LouisB does; just wanted to mention you can also solve it via "backwards" function composition here, `# + 1 & /* g`, which is equivalent to `g[# + 1] &`. (See the docs for `RightComposition`.)